# neon-animated-pages does not animate just appears in window

Tags: polymer

Just watched the latest polycast video on neon-animation-pages, and tried a basic setup, but my animation doesn't work. It appears in the window but thats it. This is the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src='../../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">
    <link rel="import" href="x-module">
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

    <neon-animated-pages class="flex" selected="1">
        <x-module></x-module>
    </neon-animated-pages>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/neon-animation/animations/slide-from-right-animation.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">


    <dom-module id="x-module">
        <style>

        </style>

        <template>
           <paper-material>
               <h1>HELO</h1>
           </paper-material>
        </template>

        <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'x-module',
            behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior,
            Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior],
            properties:{
                animationConfig:{
                    value: function() {
                        return {
                            'entry': {
                            name: 'slide-from-right-animation',
                            node: this,
                            timing:{
                                duration: 10
                            },
                        },
                        'exit': {
                            name: 'slide-right-animation',
                            node: this,
                            timing:{
                                duration: 10
                            },
                        }
                    };
                 }
              }
           },
        });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
```

I added the timing property to see if maybe it was just happening really fast. I'm sure I am just doing something dumb, but I have read the readme and and the demos. I cant see what is wrong

Comment: 10 ms is too short, try increasing it to say, 400?

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the response. I have tried with all sorts of times. Doesnt seem to make a difference, it just blinks on and off screen

Comment: Also, your pages element has only one child but its selected property is set to 1, shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: i have been using $0.selected=0 in chrome to test, i set it to 1 to exit, but yes you are right it should be 0 for production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that, you need to provide at least two elements inside `neon-animated-pages` so it knows what to transit from/to.

To test it, just add another `x-element` inside -

```
<neon-animated-pages class="flex" selected="1">
    <x-module></x-module>
    <x-module></x-module>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

Comment: Justin you are 100% right, I knew it was just me doing something dumb. Thank you for the help. Keep well